# Ada: Fraction part of Float/Fixed as Integer

Tags: floating-point, ada

In Ada, I would like to separate out a number like 12.345 out into two distinct integers:

```
whole : integer := 12;
fraction : integer := 345;
```

The Whole part is easy, but I don't know how to get the Fraction part.

My starting idea is:

```
12.345 mod Integer(12.345)
```

which will return 0.345, and could be multiplied by the inverse magnitude (in this case ×1000), but I don't know how to count the amount of digits either.

Comment: there are two problems here: 1. how do you distinguish 12.345 from 12.0345 in your representation? 2. in case of round-off errors, the number of digits after the decimal is not well-defined (i.e. what about 12.3450001. note that in binary representation, no fractional decimal number can be exactly represented).

Comment: @burnpanck, that's a good point, I forgot about leading 0's... I'll have to consider a different representation method. I've been toying around with common fractions (1/2, 5/4, etc) as opposed to decimal fractions like floating points, and have been having good luck with them. They might be necessary for what I need to do.

Comment: @burnpanck: *Most* fractional decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly. Some can, for example `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.875`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right! The problem is the denominator, which in floating-point has to be a power of two. A decimal number with `n` digits after the decimal point however has `5^n` in the prime decomposition of it's denominator, unless some of those fives are cancelled in the numerator. Thus, a decimal number is representable exactly in floating point if and only if the prime decomposition of the fractional digits contains as many fives as there are fractional digits.

Comment: I'm curious why you can't copy the number to an integer value, then subtract the integer from the float (give just the decimal). From there you can multiply by 1000 (or whatever you want your least significant digit to be) and then integerize the result to cut off the tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full Answer but this gets the fractional part as a string to enable further manipulation to retreive it as an integer:

```
with Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Remainder is 
   package Fio is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(Float);

   X : constant Float := 12.345;
   X_Int : constant Integer := Integer (X);
   X_Rem : constant Float := Float'Remainder(X,Float (X_Int));

begin
   Fio.Put (X_Rem, Aft => 6, Exp => 0);

end Remainder;
```

Answer (score 1):

In NWS suggestion, use
    `X_Int : constant Integer := Integer(Float'Truncation(X));`
instead of
    `X_Int : constant Integer := Integer (X);`

Otherwise, the whole part of the float may be rounded up (e.g. if X = 12.99, X_Int will be 13).