# Extracting fractional part of floating point number using Ada attributes

Tags: floating-point, attributes, ada

For example:

X : float := 12.34;

How do I get the '34' without using loops?

Comment: Your question isn't quite well-defined.  Once `X` has been assigned `12.34`, nobody can see if it was actually assigned `12.34` or `12.34000`.  Please make your requirements more precise.

Comment: And what would you expect to see for 1.04? 1.004? 1.0004?

Comment: At face value, ive already answered most of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928937/ada-fraction-part-of-float-fixed-as-integer).

Comment: Please note that 12.34 cannot be stored exactly in a `float`; therefore, it is nearly impossible to get the program to do what you want.  If you want an explanation, visit http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work.  If you want to store numbers like 12.34 more exactly (which you should want to do if dealing with monetary amounts), use _decimal fixed-point_.

Answer (score 0):

The following function shows one way to get it. It first subtracts the integral portion of the number. This integral portion may actually round *up* instead of down so, if the subtraction results in a number less than zero, you need to adjust for that by adding one.

```
function FloatBit (X1: float) return float is
    X2: float;
begin
    X2 := X1 - Float(Integer(X1));
    if (X2 < 0.0) then X2 := X2 + 1.0; end if;
    return X2;
end FloatBit;
```

That returns the floating point portion which you could view with:

```
Put_Line(Float'Image(FloatBit(12.34)));
```

If you want that converted to an integer (say to two decimals), you would then simply multiply it by a hundred then take the integer portion again, something like:

```
function FloatBitAsInt (X1: float; mult: integer) return integer is
begin
    return Integer(FloatBit(X1) * Float(mult));
end FloatBitAsInt;
```

And view it with:

```
Put_Line(Integer'Image(FloatBitAsInt(12.34, 100)));
```

For an *arbitrary* number of decimals, I'm not sure you could do it without a loop, something along the lines of, aspseudo-code since I don't want Ada moving back into my fast-access storage :-)

```
while float(integer(x)) is different from x:
    multiply x by ten
```

But just keep in mind that floating point is not an exact storage method. Most numbers are close enough but not exact. Hence, this method may well end up turning numbers like `0.1` into `100000001490116119384765625` which I very much doubt is what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work. Here you return 0.34 instead of 34.

Comment: @Yony, you would then multiply it by a hundred presumably. I'll update the answer.

Comment: This works only for floating points with 2 digits after the '.' And now for any floating point.

Comment: Yony, you have to set a limit simply because of floating point inaccuracies. `0.10` may *actually* be stored as something like `0.100004002` or something like that. I'm not sure you'd want `100004002` in that case.

Comment: I would want the exact representation of the number, even if it something like 0.100004 as long as there is no loop involved

Comment: I don't know Ada, but isn't there a way to turn it into text, remove the part before the decimal dot (and the dot itself) and then turn the remaining string into an integer again? That seems like the only simple way to achieve this. Then, `0.100004` would result in `100004`. And no loops.